# Nginx goaccess date/time/log format not parsing

Tags: logging, nginx, load-balancing, goaccess

Basically i have a log lines like this:

```
2015/12/13 07:58:59 [error] 1733#0: *125782 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 80.246.130.210, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.56.101:80/favicon.ico", host: "abc.com", referrer: "http://example.com/wert"
```

Which date/time/log format that i should use?

Answer (score 1):

The following works for your log format:

```
date-format %Y/%m/%d
time-format %H:%M:%S
log-format %d %t %^: %^: %^: %h,%^"%r",%^"%^",%^"%v",%^"%R"
```

I did not see any status code and request size, though.